# SQL Array value for first item is being overwritten by the second item

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, loops

I'm trying to put together a system where a letter is auto generated from 2 tables. One table houses all of the content for the letter while another has a list of people who are to receive the specific letter. There can be multiple people receiving the same letter so I'm trying to do a join and loop to generate each of the letters.

My **Problem** is I'm running into the first value that is returned when reading from the array is the second entry from the database. IE I should be having (*Rob, Jess, Alex*) outputted but instead I'm getting (*Jess, Jess, Alex*).

I'm not sure where my problem is stemming from.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM S.dbo.letters l INNER JOIN 
       S.dbo.ds d ON l.sID= d.sID
       WHERE l.id=@primaryID";

 SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, dbconn);

 dbconn.Open();
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primaryID", 1);//Session["primIDedit"]

 SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 ArrayList letterInfo = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList dFname = new ArrayList();
 myReader.Read();

 while (myReader.Read())
 {

     dFname.Add(myReader["dfname"]);
     foreach (string i in dFname)
     {
     Label txtLabel1 = new Label(); //Generating a label
     txtLabel1.Text = i.ToString();
     ph1.Controls.Add(txtLabel1); //writing to a placeholder on the aspx page
     //for now I'm just wanting to return all values.
     }

     sName.Text = myReader[1].ToString() 
                  + " " + myReader[3].ToString() + " " + 
                  myReader[2].ToString();
     paragraph1.Text = myReader[9].ToString();
     paragraph2.Text = myReader[10].ToString();
     paragraph3.Text = myReader[11].ToString();
     signoff.Text = myReader[12].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain the relevant columns in the two tables? And what exactly due you intend to receive?

Comment: Are you attempting to make the code cryptic? Using `SELECT *` and then `myReader[n]` is baffling

Comment: Why do you call  myReader.Read(); before the while loop? This will cause the first iteration in the wile loop is the second item in the data reader since you've already called Read().

Comment: @TJ the two tables are letters and donors. The sID is the variable that I have that groups the donors so I can have a letter that goes to the group, but broken into the individual donors.

Comment: @christiandev why is this baffling? I should mention that this isn't a HUGE database, just 14 columns. And I use almost all 14 to generate the letters, more code than what you see for that part.

Comment: @Martijn van Put One of the answers below mentioned that. Its been a long time since I've worked with while loops. I think my thought process was along the lines of, oh I got to call read so the while loop will fire. I'm going to try and remove that line tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Jobokai, take this line for example `sName.Text = myReader[1].ToString() + " " + myReader[3].ToString() + " " + myReader[2].ToString();`, it's impossible for anyone to determine what's going on here - I'm assuming this could be a result of *FirstName + MiddleName + LastName* or it could be *Title + FirstName +  LastName*, the point is, using `Ordinal` instead of field names is dangerous and hard to read.

Comment: @christiandev Thanks for pointing that out. I'll probably transition into using the field names.

Comment: @Jobokai, no problem - if someone changes the order of the fields in the DB, the code will break, so you will guard against such a scenario.

Comment: @christiandev Only thing there, I'm the DB admin, and the developer, graphic designer, photographer, and video guru. So that someone would be me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made assumptions here, but I would start by creating two classes...

```
public class LetterInfo
{
   public List<Recipient> Recipients {get; set;}
   public string Paragraph1 {get; set;}
   public string Paragraph2 {get; set;}
   public string Paragraph3 {get; set;}
   etc

   public LetterInfo(){
    Recipients = new List<Recipient>();
   }
}

public class Recipient
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public string MiddleName {get; set;}
}
```

Then, alter your db code to look something like this...

```
using (Sqldbconn dbconn = new Sqldbconn(connStr))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT l.Field, d.field FROM S.dbo.letters l 
                INNER JOIN S.dbo.ds d ON l.sID= d.sID WHERE l.id=@primaryID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), dbconn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primaryID", 1);//Session["primIDedit"]

        dbconn.Open();

        LetterInfo letterInfo = new LetterInfo();
        var counter = 0;

        using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                 var recipient = new Recipient();
                 recipient.FirstName = myReader["dfname"].ToString()
                 recipient.LastName = myReader["..."].ToString()
                 ....
                 letterInfo.Recipients.Add(recipient);

                 //only need to populate the letterinfo once.
                 if (counter == 0){
                     //use field name here, not the ordinal number
                     letterInfo.Paragraph1 = myReader[9].ToString();
                     letterInfo.Paragraph2 = myReader[10].ToString();
                     letterInfo.Paragraph3 = myReader[11].ToString();
                     ....
                  }

                     counter++;
                  }                   
            }
    }
```

You can then use the `letterInfo` object to populate your form.

You could also move this into some kind of *data helper class*, and call if from your code-behind...

```
public LetterInfo GetLetterInfo(int primaryId){
  //the code above in here
}
```

Your code behind could then look like...

```
LetterInfo letter = dbHelper.GetLetterInfo(1);
```

**p.s.** I wrote this in Notepad++, so I expect compile errors :)

Comment: Thank you I'll try this tomorrow and see what I come up with.

Comment: @Jobokai, the issue is definitely `myReader.Read();`, which I have removed above - but you should also consider the other changes to make the code more readable :)

Comment: So I had to make some tweaks, and probably generated the letter in a more complicated way than necessary, but I got everything working thanks to your code and method. Thank you for taking the time to make the answer, I'm not sure if I could have come up with that method on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line before while loop.

```
myReader.Read();
```

and check the subscript value of myreader object using breakpoints while debugging

```
 sName.Text = myReader[1].ToString() 
              + " " + myReader[3].ToString() + " " + 
              myReader[2].ToString();
 paragraph1.Text = myReader[9].ToString();
 paragraph2.Text = myReader[10].ToString();
 paragraph3.Text = myReader[11].ToString();
 signoff.Text = myReader[12].ToString();
```

Comment: I'll try removing the my reader.read and see what happens. I have a feeling that this is the bug.